# Validation message position is not updating on resize of window

Tags: validation, jquery-mobile, window-resize, jquery-validation-engine

I am facing **problem with showing validation message in a proper position when change the size of the window**, *am using jquery validation engine along jquery mobile*.

> When I submit the form the validation message will appear at correct
>   position when rotate the screen or resize it the message will not move
>   to its proper field it will remain in the 1st position itself.

Please guide regarding this.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

passing the parameter **autoPositionUpdate: true** in **validationEngine()** will fix this issue but this works in 2.6 version not in 2.2 version of jquery validation engine